# Adding Border Layout In Accordion Layout

Tags: accordion, gxt, extjs

Can we add a content panel having border layout to a panle that is having an Accordion Layout. we are trying to put our central panle as well as west panel on a panle which displays this in accordion view. But not able to do this as the data is not displaying kinldy request to suggest.

Regards
Satish

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
public class test extends Composite {
    private ContentPanel accordionPanel;
    private ContentPanel borderPanel;
    private ContentPanel westPanel;
    private ContentPanel centerPanel;

    public test() {

        accordionPanel = new ContentPanel();
        accordionPanel.setLayout(new AccordionLayout());

        borderPanel = new ContentPanel();
        borderPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        westPanel = new ContentPanel();
        borderPanel.add(westPanel, new BorderLayoutData(LayoutRegion.WEST));

        centerPanel = new ContentPanel();
        borderPanel.add(centerPanel, new BorderLayoutData(LayoutRegion.CENTER));
        accordionPanel.add(borderPanel);
        initComponent(accordionPanel);
    }

}
```